# Gemfire Exception handling

Tags: java, spring, exception, gemfire

I have a Local Cache which is caching data from a web service. If suppose the web service is down, then definitely there is an exception thrown. I would like to handle this exception and return previously cached values from the method. Can any one tell me, Does Gemfire has any such exception handling feature to handle such exceptions? Im using annotation based caching.

Comment: Are you connecting to the distributed system as a member/peer? Or are you connecting as a client?

Comment: Im connecting as a client..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the Spring @Cacheable capability.  With that framework, the cache is checked first so, if there is an answer in the cache it will not call the web service at all (so it won't matter whether it is up or down).